# Power BI, cumulative sum Monthly Reports display in a Yearly Chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

In Power BI, I have a bunch of cumulative sum monthly reports example current Employee count

so in line charts, it automatically shows the dates as years in the X-axis. you can drill down to see the monthly details of any year. by default the chart SUM all the months to show the year. i want the chart to show the last month's value from every year at the year level

if I showed the report in a line chart
at monthly level ( no issue) if i dril up
at year level (it should show the value for December , PBI "SUM" the values which is wrong,)

I tried

```
    count for December = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('data'[count]),
    'data'[Date].[Month] IN { "December" },
    ALL('data'[Date].[MonthNo])
)
```

at year level ( no issue) if i drill dawon
at month level (it should show the value for December for all months)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: so in line charts, it automatically shows the dates as years in the X-axis.
 you can drill down to see the monthly details of any year.

by default the chart SUM all the months to show the year . i want the chart to show the last month's value from evry year at year level .